# iOS: the function (IBAction)inputChanged:(id)sender is very slow when displaying a tableview with the result of the search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I added a field, and when I tap the firsts characters, it shows me the result of the query in a sqlite, directly in a tableview generated just behind the field. The problem, is that it is very slow.

```
- (IBAction)inputChanged:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
        if ([[self.searchLabel text] length] >= 2)
        {
            self->_results = [[searchDB database] searchDBResults:[self.searchLabel text]];
            self.results = self->_results;

            if (self.results.count > 0)
            {
                //tableview
                self->_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
                if (IS_IPAD_DEVICE)
                {
                    self->_tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self->searchLabel.frame.origin.x, 320, self->viewPreview.frame.origin.x - 40, self->statisticView.frame.origin.y - 430);
                }
                else
                {
                    self->_tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self->searchLabel.frame.origin.x, self->searchLabel.frame.origin.y + 44, self.view.frame.size.width - 12, self->statisticView.frame.origin.y + 80);
                }
                self->_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.35];
                self->_tableView.dataSource = self;
                self->_tableView.delegate = self;
                self->_tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

                [self.tableView reloadData];

                [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: use coredata & NSFetchedResultController [Go to this tutorial.](https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3)

Comment: @Animesh Thanks for your answer, but I don't like CoreData. I removed it three years ago because it was not good for what I needed.

Comment: Performing DB search in a main queue is not a good idea, generally you should dispatch execution block to main queue to update UI only. I'd suggest dispatching the search to a different (background?) queue and update UI from main queue using another dispatch block once you get the results.